# Connecting from local server to Android through internet

Tags: java, android

I am asking for help if possible:

1. I want to send credentials from android application to a Local
   server
2. The Local server has application to check the validation
   of these credentials, I want to send response back to the Android.

Then if all ok , I want to send  more Data to the Server from Android Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create an API that receive those credentials and sent response to the Android Device. There are a lot of other technology / programming languages with whose you can create an API: C#, Java, PHP, etc.

- This is for Android Client: [INTEGRATE A REST API INTO ANDROID APPLICATION IN
  LESS THAN 15 MINUTES](http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes)
- If you prefer **PHP** as API: [Create a RESTFULL API in PHP](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html)
- If you prefer **c#** as API: [How to call .NET Web Api from Android App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQ8Mu7-s_Xk)

Note: this is possible to make the API with Java too if you want but I didn't have usefull links for that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response , i am gonna ccheck it and update what will be new.

Comment: @Nijim: Good, if my reponse satisfy you, please consider to vote up and/or validate my answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks again for the helpful info. 
This is the Android part , i am also asking about building a server API to recive these credentials and check them. also give the response.

Comment: @Nijim : check my response, PHP and C# is for building API ;-)

Comment: Sorry to ask , Is it not possible in Java?

Comment: @Nijim yes it is possible but I think this is a little bit harder than in c# or PHP but well If you feel comfortable with ava, let's try this! I've found this article that looks brilliant but I've never used that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html